# Localhost Configuration

Tags: localhost

how to run php program, i have install Apache,mysql,phpmyadmin.I don't know to configure files and directories to run php project on local host. Please give me solution step by step.

Comment: Open up software center, search and install `php`*, and then try the answer given by AgentCool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to configure anything.

Just make sure your `apache` and `mysql` services are running. Then open your terminal and type

`sudo nano /var/www/html/echo.php`

then add the following

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo " Hi"
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Open your browser and goto

`locahost/echo.php`

If you see `Hi`, then everything is fine. If you see something wrong or a error let us know.